# error index beyond bounds

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray, ccsprite

```
    -(id) init
    {
      if( (self=[super init])) {
        _targets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        temp = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4",nil];
        tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:temp];
        resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self thelogic];
      }
  return self;
    }

    -(void)thelogic
    {
      int i;
      int count = 4;
      for (i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
      int index = arc4random() % (count - i);
      [resultArray addObject:[tempArray objectAtIndex:index]];
      CCSprite *target = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",  [tempArray objectAtIndex:index]]];
      target.tag = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tempArray objectAtIndex:index]] integerValue];
      [self addChild:target];
      [_targets addObject:target];
      [tempArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
     }
    }

    -(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
      [_targets removeAllObjects];
      [self thelogic];
    }
```

from the up code, I get three different numbers and they make three sprites with different image when enter this scene, and I want to touch the screen, the three old sprites will be removed, and three new sprites will show, but the up code always crashes, so how should I fix it? thanks

Comment: please post the exact error message you get when the app crashes...

Comment: @sergio error message is `*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]`, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to understand what you are trying to do in your `theLogic` method, but I would suggest you to replace

```
 int index = arc4random() % (count - i);
```

with

```
 int index = arc4random() % [tempArray count];
```

This will fix the crash, but I doubt that your program will work as expected. Indeed, you only populate `tempArray` in the init method; the first call to `theLogic` will remove all of its elements, and as far as I see the array is not populated anymore. So, when you make `ccTouchesBegan` be called and then `theLogic`, tempArray will be empty.

Sorry if I am missing any points.

Comment: in `thelogic`, I try to add three sprites, each sprite has different tag and different image.

Comment: @DMusic: thanks for your comment. Could you check if my suggestion about `index` fixes the crash?